# Cast Guid array to Object array

Tags: c#, .net

Why does

```
var value = new Guid[]{};
var b = (object[])value;
```

results in

```
Cannot cast 'value' (which has an actual type of 'System.Guid[]') to 'object[]'
```

?

UPDATE

Sorry for inaccuracy. The real code is:

```
    private void SetEditors(object value)
    {
        var array = value as object[];
        ...
    }
```

and array is null if value is Guid array.

Comment: Because a `Guid-Array` is not an `Object-Array`. You could use `value.Cast<Object>().ToArray()`

Comment: Sure, the array doesn't contain objects, it contains Guids.  It is structurally different.  Converting a Guid to an object requires a boxing conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the "why" part- only arrays of reference types are covariant.

So you can write:

```
string[] x = new string[10];
object[] y = x;
```

But you can't write:

```
int[] x = new int[10];
object[] y = x;
```

Personally I think it's a shame that even the first version is allowed, but that's a different story.

This is all detailed in section 6.1.6 of the C# 4 spec (Implicit Reference Conversions):

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> - ...
> - From an array-type S with an element type S<sub>E</sub> to an array-type T with an element type T<sub>E</sub> provided all of the following are true:
>
>   - S and T differ only in element type. In other words, S and T have the same number of dimensions.
>   - Both S<sub>E</sub> and T<sub>E</sub> are reference-types.
>   - An implicit reference conversion exists from S<sub>E</sub> to T<sub>E</sub>

Comment: Ok, I see your point. but what about updated code? what could you advice for that case?

Comment: @Chesheersky: It's exactly the same: there's no reference type conversion to `object[]`, so the result of `as` is null. If you want to see whether it's *any* kind of array, use `Array` instead.

Comment: Works great =)
Fact that cast to string[] worked fine confused me a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
var b = value.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

`GUID` is `object` , however `GUID[]` isn't `object[]` , you have to up-cast every element in the array